# How to get range time in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Basically what I want try to do is to get shift in range between

[image]

already get with this where

```
where @param_value_from_hour between From_Hour and To_Hour
```

it works when @param_value_from_hour let say 16:00 but what if I have to search @param_value_from_hour with 19:00?

Comment: you need to make some kind of conversion I guess, in order to make that query (or a similar one) work... like adding one day to the 'To_Hour' value...
Or maybe you could just check if the person belongs to shift 1... if not, he surely belongs to shift 2 ;)

Comment: oh I forget to mention that max shift is 3, hmm, about some kind of conversion, I don't get it, but I think I will try your idea about adding one day o the to_hour value, thank you for your respon

Comment: Is your data always `07:00:00 - 18:00:00` and `18:00:00 - 07:00:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the logic is that, if the end of the period is earlier than the start of the period then the period is assumed to span midnight (if it isn't, we need some other form of convention or things get hopelessly ambiguous):

```
where
   (@param_value_from_hour between From_Hour and To_Hour) or
   (To_Hour < From_Hour and
       (@param_value_from_hour < To_Hour or
        From_Hour < @param_value_from_hour)
   )
```

Should get approximately what you want (adjust `<` for `<=` if required)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `time` columns to `datetime` and compare

```
declare @param_value_from_hour varchar(20) = '19:00'
;with myTable as (
    select * 
    from (
        values 
            (1, '7:00:00', '18:00:00')
            , (2, '18:00:00', '7:00:00')
    ) t(Shift, From_Hour, To_Hour)
)

select
    * 
from
    myTable
where
    cast('20180101 ' + @param_value_from_hour as datetime) between 
    cast('20180101 ' + From_Hour as datetime) 
    and cast('20180101 ' + To_Hour as datetime) + case when From_Hour < To_Hour then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    Shift INT,
    FromHour TIME,
    ToHour TIME
    );

INSERT INTO Data (Shift, FromHour, ToHour) VALUES
(1, '07:00:00', '18:00:00'),
(2, '18:00:00', '07:00:00');

DECLARE @Param TIME= '16:00:00'; --Change that to '19:00:00'

SELECT *
FROM Data
WHERE CAST(@Param AS DATETIME) BETWEEN 
      CAST(FromHour AS DATETIME)
        AND
    (CASE 
         WHEN (@Param >= '18:00:00' AND ToHour = '07:00:00') 
             THEN DATEADD(D, 1, CAST(ToHour AS DATETIME)) 
         ELSE CAST(ToHour AS DATETIME) 
    END)
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all your valuable respon

so this is the answer combine from 2 answer

```
declare @param_value_from_hour varchar(20) = '19:00'

;with myTable as (
    select * 
    from (
        values 
            (1, '07:00:00', '15:00:00')
            , (2, '15:00:00', '23:00:00')
            , (3, '23:00:00', '07:00:00')
    ) t(Shift, From_Hour, To_Hour)
)

select
    * 
from
    myTable
where
   (@param_value_from_hour between From_Hour and To_Hour) or
   (To_Hour < From_Hour and
       (@param_value_from_hour < To_Hour or
        From_Hour < @param_value_from_hour)
   )
```

thank you guys, you're awesome!!