# how-to-get-range-time-in-sql-server part 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Related to this question

[How to get range time in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557068/how-to-get-range-time-in-sql-server/48557458#48557458)

I want to get shift 2 when my input value is **18:00**

here examples from above post :

```
declare @param_value_from_hour varchar(20) = '18:00'
;with myTable as (
    select * 
    from (
        values 
            (1, '7:00:00', '18:00:00')
            , (2, '18:00:00', '7:00:00')
    ) t(Shift, From_Hour, To_Hour)
)

select
    * 
from
    myTable
where
   (@param_value_from_hour between From_Hour and To_Hour) or
   (To_Hour < From_Hour and
       (@param_value_from_hour < To_Hour or
        From_Hour < @param_value_from_hour)
   )
```

but with that solution I just get shift 1, can anyone help what I missing here thank you

Comment: Repeat the examples here, treat it as a whole new question, don't expect people to follow a link to read the question then go back to write an answer, then follow the link against to check something, etc, etc.  Keep everything we need to know in this one question.

Comment: oke thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE
  (
        @param_value_from_hour >= From_Hour
    AND @param_value_from_hour <  To_Hour
  )
  OR
  (
    From_Hour > To_Hour
    AND
    (
         @param_value_from_hour >= From_Hour
      OR @param_value_from_hour <  To_Hour
    )
  )
```

Comment: thank you @MatBailie but still got the same result here

Comment: ***PLEASE*** tell me you're using a `TIME` data type, and not a `VARCHAR()` data type!?

Comment: ah yes, i'm using time data type, sorry I forget to mention that

Comment: @Poli - Then it's your test that's wrong.  Using `TIME` data types this works fine, but your CTE based test uses strings.  Try using `CAST('18:00' AS TIME)` and `CAST(7:00:00 AS TIME)`, etc.  See my link in the comment above.  *(In your example using `'18:00'` is a problem using strings it's Less Than `'18:00:00'`.  It's also less than `'7:00:00'`, which is another inconsistency in your test; it should be `'07:00:00'` if you're using strings.)*

Comment: yes I test and it is work perfecly now, and still I test with others possibility, thank you very much for your valuable response.

Answer (score 0):

poli, Do you have to have myTable as CTE only?? Problem here is data types of "Time" columns.. Please check if temporary table / similar approach where you can mention data types work for you

```
declare @param_value_from_hour varchar(20) = '18:00'
declare @myTable Table (Shift int, From_Hour time, To_Hour time)

insert into @myTable (Shift, From_Hour, To_Hour) values (1, '7:00:00', '18:00:00')
insert into @myTable (Shift, From_Hour, To_Hour) values (2, '18:00:00', '7:00:00')

 Select * from @myTable
where
   (@param_value_from_hour >= From_Hour and @param_value_from_hour < To_Hour) or
   (To_Hour < From_Hour and
   (@param_value_from_hour < To_Hour or
    From_Hour <= @param_value_from_hour)
   )
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` is still a problem because the parameter `18:00` will then also *(incorrectly)* match row `1`.

Comment: Aah...Sorry... Missed to check that he needs only shift 2...how about changing where? I have edited first where condition..

Comment: The rest of it is fine.  Provided the OP's data isn't `VARCHAR()` *(because if it's `VARCHAR()` then formatting makes a difference.  `'18:00'` being "less than" both `'18:00:00'` and `'7:00:00'` when using strings...)*